# How do I import a spreadsheet to create a list, but specify which column should be the "title"?

Tags: list, list-definition

I'm not a programmer, just a frustrated user. Is there a way for me when I create a custom list by importing a spreadsheet to specify which column should become the "title" for each row in the list?